# Checking for an area of the screen to change then sending a message to a skype group conversation

Tags: autoit

I'm looking for some help creating a bit of code that will look at an area of my screen and then after 60 seconds for it to check if it has changed.

After it has changed I am then trying to send a message over skype to a group of people with a message however the problem i'm having is that I can't change chat easily using ControlCommand, MouseMove, MouseClick, ControlSend...etc

I even tried MouseClickPlus to click when minimised but that didn't work at all.

The coordinates in question for the box that I'm trying to look at are: `86, 109, 280, 109`

If anyone knows ways to do this I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the `Skype UDF` and `PixelChecksum` or maybe even `ImageSearch` with `ImageCapture`

I would say the best way to check if the said area changes is using `PixelChecksum` which can be used like below.

#### `PixelChecksum` Code Example 1

```
Local $GetAreaChecksumOne = PixelChecksum(86, 109, 280, 109)
Sleep(60000)
Local $GetAreaChecksumTwo = PixelChecksum(86, 109, 280, 109)
While $GetAreaChecksumOne <> $GetAreaChecksumTwo
    $GetAreaChecksumTwo = PixelChecksum(86, 109, 280, 109)
    Sleep(1000)
    ConsoleWrite("Match not found")
WEnd
```

Or a more normal way of doing it would be:

#### `PixelChecksum` Code Example 2

```
Local $GetAreaChecksumOne = PixelChecksum(86, 109, 280, 109)
While $GetAreaChecksumOne = PixelChecksum(86, 109, 280, 109)
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

Refrence Link: [`PixelChecksum`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelChecksum.htm)

To send a skype message you'll need the [`Skype UDF`](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/121767-skype-udf-v12-sep-15-2013/) if you want to send messages to a favourite chat in Skype.

#### `Skype` Code Example

```
#include <Skype.au3>
Local $sTopic = "Bookmarked (favourited) chat name here"
Local $aBookMarkedChat = _Skype_ChatGetBookmarked(), $oChattmp = 0
For $i = 0 To UBound($aBookMarkedChat) -1
    $oChattmp = $aBookMarkedChat[$i]
    If _Skype_ChatGetTopic($oChattmp) = $sTopic Then
        _Skype_ChatSendMessage($oChattmp, "Message here")
    EndIf
Next
```

If you want to go down an imagecapture and imagesearch route then use something similar to below, however again you'll need the [`ImageSearch UDF`](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/)

#### `ScreenCapture` and `ImageSearch` Code Example

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
Local $XCoords = 0
Local $YCoords = 0
_ScreenCapture_Capture(@DesktopDir & "Compare.png", 86, 109, 280, 109)
Sleep(60000)
$Compare = _ImageSearch(@DesktopDir & "Compare.png", 1, $XCoords, $YCoords, 5)
While $Compare = 0
    $Compare = _ImageSearch(@DesktopDir & "Compare.png", 1, $XCoords, $YCoords, 5)
Sleep(1000)
WEnd
FileDelete(@DesktopDir & "Compare.png")
```

If you want to make a more througah ImageSearch then use ImageSearchArea (faster and for what you need it's better)

Comment: No problem, I've added another alternative version of the checking the area you mentioned. Hopefully one of the solutions will suit your needs :)